# What kind of argument is needed when invoking from service to component? ts(2554)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angular8

I'm currently on an amateur stage in angular web development currently on dealing subcollection using angular and firestore (with angularfire2).

I'm trying to populate my component with both the main task and a subtask (subcollection here).

However I don't know what kind of argument should I put since I always encounter

Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) on my component.

Here is my code for the service

```
 getqtask(){
    this.qtaskCollection = this.boardtask.collection('qboardtask', ref => ref.orderBy('deadline','asc'));
    this.qtask = this.qtaskCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(a =>{
        const data=a.payload.doc.data() as qtaskmodel;
        data.id=a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }
    ))
    return this.qtask;
  }


  getsubtask(qboardtaskID:qtaskmodel,subtaskID:subtaskmodel){
    this.subtaskCollection = this.subtaskq.collection(`qboardtask/${qboardtaskID}/subtask/${subtaskID}`, ref => ref.orderBy('deadline','asc'));
    this.subtask = this.subtaskCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(a =>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as subtaskmodel;
        data.id=a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });

    }
    ))
    return this.subtask;
  }
```

and here is the code which I need to provide arguments

```
    this.boardServices.getqtask().subscribe(boardobs =>{
      console.log(boardobs);
      this.boardlist = boardobs;
    })

    this.subtaskServices.getsubtask().subscribe(sbobs =>{
      console.log(sbobs);
      this.subtasklist = sbobs;
    })
```

.getsubtask() is asking for 2 arguments which i'm currently no knowledge how to provide.

Hope you can help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`getsubtask(qboardtaskID:qtaskmodel,subtaskID:subtaskmodel)`  expects 2 arguments `qboardtaskID` and `subtaskID`, While calling it from component, you didn't pass any paramer `this.boardServices.getqtask()`.

So you have to pass `qboardtaskID` and `subtaskID`

Like this:

```
this.boardServices.getqtask(qboardtaskID, subtaskID)
```